# How to load resource as cardinal in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm creating application that will read part (512KB) of embedded resource (8MB) and write it to one of physical drives, but when i trying it to compile i get error `Incompatible types: 'Cardinal' and 'TResourceStream'` and now i'm trying to find out how to load resource as cardinal without saving it anywhere as file or make it work another way. Is it even possible?

DOS.dpr

```
program DOS;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  ShellAPI,
  Classes;

type
  memory = array [0..524287] of byte;
{$R 'DOS.RES'}

var
  HDD,nr,nw : cardinal;
  MEM       : memory;
  DOS       : TResourceStream;
begin
 DOS := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DOS', RT_RCDATA);
 SetFilePointer(DOS,0,NIL,FILE_BEGIN);
 ReadFile(DOS,MEM,524288,nr,NIL);
 DOS.Free;

 HDD := CreateFileA('\\.\PhysicalDrive0',GENERIC_ALL,FILE_SHARE_WRITE + FILE_SHARE_READ,NIL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
 SetFilePointer(HDD,0,NIL,FILE_BEGIN);
 WriteFile(HDD,MEM,524288,nw,NIL);
 CloseHandle(HDD);
end.
```

Comment: SetFilePointer expects a file handle whereas you're passing it a TResourceStream. This is what the compiler complains about. It is telling you the same thing with somewhat less words. Perhaps you should be starting from  more basic stuff, in the meantime learning how the compiler communicates.

Comment: You will never succeed in treating a resource as a file, but you can instead treat it as a stream

Answer (score 4):

`TResourceStream` is not a file, so you can't call `SetFilePointer()` and `ReadFile()` on it. `TResourceStream` is a `TStream` descendant. `TStream` has a `Position` property, and `Read/Buffer()` and `Seek()` methods, eg:

```
program DOS;

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, ShellAPI, Classes;

{$R 'DOS.RES'}

var
  HDD: THandle;
  nr: Integer;
  nw : DWORD;
  mem : array [0..524287] of Byte; // <-- for such large sizes, you should use a dynamic array instead...
  rs : TResourceStream;
begin
  rs := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DOS', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    rs.Position := 0; // <-- redundant!
    // rs.Seek(0, soBeginning); // <-- this, too
    nr := rs.Read(mem, sizeof(mem));
  finally
    rs.Free;
  end;

  HDD := CreateFile('\\.\PhysicalDrive0', GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  try
    SetFilePointer(HDD, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN); // <-- redundant!
    WriteFile(HDD, mem, nr, nw, nil);
  finally
    CloseHandle(HDD);
  end;
end.
```

Alternatively, `TResourceStream` is a `TMemoryStream` descendant, so you don't need the byte array at all:

```
program DOS;

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, ShellAPI, Classes;

{$R 'DOS.RES'}

var
  HDD: THandle;
  nw : DWORD;
  rs : TResourceStream;
begin
  rs := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DOS', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    HDD := CreateFile('\\.\PhysicalDrive0', GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    try
      WriteFile(HDD, rs.Memory^, rs.Size, nw, nil);
    finally
      CloseHandle(HDD);
    end;
  finally
    rs.Free;
  end;
end.
```